# Twig - Loop returns only 1 result

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, twig

i'm trying to make a loop in php while using twig and inside this loop,
i am creating a parameter which contains the record from the database query.

The problem is that when I use the parameter in my HTML file, it only return 1 record from the while loop, even if there are 3 or 4 or even more..

This is the php code I have:

```
public function getWidgetsByName($name)
{
     global $params;
     $get = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM profile_items
                              WHERE category = 'widget'
                              AND username = '". $name ."'");
     if($get)
     {
          while($key = $get->fetch())
          {
               $params["profile_widget_name"] = $key['name'];
          }
     }
}
```

And this is the HTML parameter in my HTML twig rendered file:

```
{{ profile_widget_name }}
```

The paremeters just get rendered how they are supposed to be rendered:

```
echo $twig->render('app/views/'. $_REQUEST['p'] .'.html', $params);
```

And yes the $params variable is an array, in the config it file it first gets used as $params = array("..." => "..."); and I add things to this array by doing $params["..."] = "...";

So, I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance,
Best Regards.

Comment: I'm struggling to see exactly what's going on here. What's returned from the database? Where's the loop in Twig that's failing? What are you expecting it to look like?

Comment: Okay so for example i'm trying to loop trough all the results which have a category of widget and the username which needs to be given in the function. For example i have 3 results with category widget and username 'Explorer'. The results I should get are: 'profileWidget', 'guestbookWidget' and 'friendsWidget'. But the problem is that it only returns 'friendsWidget'

Comment: You need to update your question with the Twig code you've written, what you'd like to be output and what's actually being output. At the moment, it's not clear.

Comment: I editted my example, see above comment.

Comment: I don't see any Twig templates that you're attempting to render. Your question refers to a loop, but I don't see any Twig loop.

Comment: I'm setting a tWig parameter inside the php loop which should output ALL the results, but it only returns one.

Comment: And what do you want Twig to output? Can you edit the question to include the HTML. You do need to do some of the work yourself here to get a good answer.

Comment: `$params` is an array, but you're basically just setting a single value in that array, `$params["profile_widget_name"]`, overwriting it for every iteration of your loop (eventually it'll be equal to the name from the last row of your query).  Instead you need to pass an array containing a row for each row of your query, to the Twig template.  Where you then loop over it.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example if that is possible and doesn't take too much work? I don't really get it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the value of `$params["profile_widget_name"]` is just one string. Every time you go through the `while` loop, you overwrite the previous value of the key with the current value.

So when you pass `$params` to Twig, the value of `profile_widget_name` is the value of `name` in the last row of the database to be selected.

I think what you want instead is for the value of `profile_widget_name` to be an array. Then every time you go through the loop, the current value of `name` is added to the array, instead of overwriting it.

You do this by doing something like:

```
$params["profile_widget_names"][] = $key['name'];
```

Now in your Twig template, you'll need to do something like:

```
{% for profile_widget_name in profile_widget_names %}
  {{ profile_widget_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Using Multiple Parameters**

If you want multiple parameters to be on there, you can do this:

```
$params["profile_widgets"][] = [
    'pos_x' => $key['pos_x'],
    'name'  => $key['name'],
];
```

And in Twig:

```
{% for profile_widget in profile_widgets %}
  Name: {{ profile_widget.name }}
  Pos X: {{ profile_widget.pos_x }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Another question, what if I for example want another parameter to be in the for loop (profile_widget_pos_x)? I made a new for loop like 
{% for profile_widget_pos_x in profile_widget_positions_x %}
    {{ profile_widget_pos_x }}
{% endfor %}

But the problem is that it then displays the results multiplied by 2... And I think that is because I made that for loop inside the first one, but I don't know how to do it on another way...